# NullPointerException in Serialized objects

Tags: java, serialization, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a program that can save data as "data.ser" and retrieve it and output it. However, although it does the task, the program shows that there is an issue with the NullPointerException.

```
public void loadData(){
        
        ArrayList<Object> deserialized = new ArrayList<Object>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("data.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            deserialized = (ArrayList<Object>)in.readObject();
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch(IOException i  ){
            i.printStackTrace();
            
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
            c.printStackTrace();
            
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        
    }
```

The message that always pops up when I run the whole program is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at student_Copy.Main.loadData(Main.java:94)
at student_Copy.loadData.main(loadData.java:9)
```

There is also a class that retrieves the file

```
public class loadData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.loadData();
    
}
```

Comment: You need to print out the data you are sending/receiving from main. Something is returning null. Are you sending null args?

Comment: Um I am not sure, I am trying to check if there is anything null but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I fixed it! It was all because I had an array with a large index but a lot of them were empty cause U didn't fill it with objects yet.